# WCF javascript proxy cross domain prevent access database

Tags: javascript, wcf, cors

So I just follow this tutorial to implement a wcf service : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627082/How-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-JavaScript-Proxy.

In summary:

1. I wrote a WCF service and make it expose a JS proxy (like in the above tutorial)
2. I used WCF test client to test and it works perfectly
3. I wrote a dummy html page and host it on another domain. Then I cannot access the service due to CORS (Tried to resolve this but no success). So I managed to use chrome with --disable-web-security flag to hack the CORS problem (I will try to solve this later). Now I can access the service and it works fine but for the functions that have to access the database, they just return empty result.

So my question is: Is this the normal architecture for this kind of WCF service (Generating js proxy to expose service to javascript clients). I write this WCF to expose the service to mobile devices. And if yes, is the CORS that preventing me from accessing the database when calling the service from client javascript?

Comment: What you need to do is make a an ajax call to your remote WCF service. if jQuery is an option for you, the refer(which is a  easy option to make ajax call)  :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax  or try making a ajax call with raw javascript, which would be a bit tedious task.

Comment: How do I know what kind of request I need to send (like what is the parameter...)

Comment: the a have added a code sample for call wcf service via ajax call .for more info refer to  :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
     $.ajax({
         url:'<ip address/site name>/wcfService.svc/method1',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType:'json',
         data:{a:'<parameter value being sent>'}, //pass any parameter that are expected by the remote WCF service method(method1).
         success:function(response) {
             //Process the data(json/ normal data) retrieved from remote service. 
         }
     });
```

*Note:Enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` option on the remote server end for make it `CORS` compatible. Best way to do this would be to configure this under behavior level itself, instead of `service contract` or `operation contract` level.ref:blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/*

Happy Coding:)

Comment: I got a request canceled status, possibly due to CORS.

Comment: Still get a canceled status, possibly because I used a wrong parameter. So for example my C# function is like this string test(string a). What would be the right parameters to put in?

Comment: @victor: first of all your url should be proper, for eg, if your trying to access `method1` under `wcfService.svc`, then your url should be `url:'<ip address/site name>/wcfService.svc/method1'`.
secondly,the parameter can be passed like this `data:{a:'<parameter value being sent>'}`.

Comment: This is what I got for the response : {"ExceptionDetail":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":null,"Message":"The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.","StackTrace":"   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] param.....

Comment: @victor: you may need to enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on your server end. refer to this site and configure the behavior as mentioned ,it will enable that property at the behavior level,http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/

Comment: oh for that jsut add this `dataType:'json'` in the ajax call along with existing options.

Comment: I configured my server to make it support CORS. Now the pre-flight OPTIONS request got a status 405 Mehod not allowed but the actual request later got proper response( weird!). Now the requests that needs to access the database, they just return empty result to me. The other methods that never access database works perfect. Thanks

Comment: @victor: good to know that atleast something worked out. i think the retrieved from DB needs to serialised to json format before returning to client, i havent worked on Cross domain ajax request with DB access. may be you can try that option. so lets close this question then. you can create a new thread for DB access failure issue. meanwhile i`ll update my answer with what ever input i gave in the comments before.